# How to fetch exactly same results of Google Grocery stores near to me

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am wondering to find a way to fetch exactly similar results of google grocery stores near to me

I have used the below API to get nearby grocery stores

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&radius=5000&key=AIzaSyC9rFJ90pP1oHpLrqpR2B0HtUboLaHmnDw&location=45.4940475,-73.5606149&type=supermarket&rankby=prominence

but it's not showing the all popular stores with matching to google grocery stores near to me best match (attached images).

[image]

What is the way to achieve functionality by applying filters From API? please, advice appreciated if its possible immediate replay.

Thanks

Comment: Might be a good idea to remove your developer key from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The API only will gather data by distance, prominence, and type. It is up to you how you want the data be sorted/filtered and which to display to your users.

Get your data: `rankby`

> If rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is
>   specified, then one or more of keyword, name, or type is required.

If you want to rank by distance, you will need to remove radius parameter form your url.

> radius — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place
>   results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius
>   must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional
>   parameters below) is specified.

This will get you started. [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)